# parseInt returns NaN after getting first value in an integer array

Tags: javascript

I am able to push the first integer element in the array. After that it takes every input values as a NaN.

How can we remove blank spaces in the array input at runtime.
As Ryan said  readLine is returning something that isn't parseable as an integer.

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}

/////////////// ignore above this line ////////////////////


function main() {


    var n = parseInt(readLine());

    var a = [];



        for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
         /*I am able to get first input but not for next iteration input value taken as NaN*/
         var no = parseInt(readLine(),10);

         console.log(readLine())


           a.push(no);



        }







}
```

For example,

input: `1 2 3 4 5`

output: `1 NaN NaN NaN NaN`

Comment: What `readLine()` does?

Comment: I was asking about `parseInt(readLine(), 10);`

Comment: @DineshSonachalam Show us the implementation of `readLine()`

Comment: @Tushar It gets input at runtime and store in the array. I cannot figure out why it returns NaN after getting next numbers after first element.

Comment: `readLine` is returning something that isn't parseable as an integer. `console.log(readLine())` to find out what.

Comment: @DineshSonachalam If it is array, then it is expected.

Comment: @DineshSonachalam Please provide the implementation of `readLine()`

Comment: Based on your example input, it fails because it's being passed a string with whitespace. `parseInt` will fail on any input that is not a number.

Comment: var no = parseInt(readLine()) ; // I am getting an integer . From the next iteration  whatever number i am giving input is taken as NaN.Why? @Weedoze

Comment: Could you extract the code and put it in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @DineshSonachalam Again..Please provide the implementation of `readline()` function. The problem come probably from there. This function returns something that is not parseable as an integer

Comment: @ Weedoze I have added readline() please review it.

Comment: @Weedoze Can you please say what is problem occuring in my readLine function that I have added in my code when i give a next input?

Comment: @Dinesh Sonachalam  `input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split(" ");` add this on your `process.stdin.on('end', function () {` method instead of your statement  it will solve your issue.

Comment: Or you must use space instead of new line character to split into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given input `1 2 3 4 5`, it will fail because there is whitespace between the numbers. `parseInt` returns `NaN` for any input other than a number.

You can try that out yourself:

```
parseInt('1 2 3 4 5', 10) // returns 1
parseInt('12345', 10) // returns 12345
```

You can read more about it (and alternatives to `parseInt`) here: https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls

What you could do is validate the input and strip out all the slashes:

```
"1 2 3 4 5".replace(/\s/g, ""); // "12345"
```

This will make your function handle a numeric input very well while failing with other inputs. It reads like your function should handle every kind of input, instead of using RegEx to filter out stuff like spaces (and, as the old adage goes, [you now have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/))